# Config.cmake missing error in Rasberry pi cross compiling setup

Tags: opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to build a cross compiling system on ubuntu 16.04 to shorten the compile time.

I have installed the tools and copied libs from the raspberry pi and definitely a simple "Hello world" example works very well.

The problem occurred when I tried to build a program with cmake and opencv. Obviously it does not find OpenCVConfig.cmake in the host system as it only exists on rpi in the following folder:

/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4$

Can I just copy /usr/local/lib/cmake folder to host computer and manually modify the library install path or how should I do it?

Error message:

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
of the following names:

```
OpenCVConfig.cmake
opencv-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)


SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

# Where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspi/sysroot)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")

# Search for programs only in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries and headers only in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -Wall -fopenmp")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fopenmp")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

find_library(LIB_RT rt)

list(APPEND LINK_LIBS 
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)


include_directories(
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


set(SOURCE opencvdemo.cpp)

add_executable(vc_opencv_demo ${SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(vc_opencv_demo ${LIB_RT} ${LINK_LIBS})
```

Comment: Are you using `python`?

Comment: I am using c++.

Comment: What is the command result of `pkg-config --modversion opencv4` ?

Comment: pkg-config --modversion opencv4
Package opencv4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv4' found

Comment: This is weird. Opencv is installed and it compiles well in RPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use in general some cmake option for linux cross compiling:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/devel/rasp-pi-rootfs)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/devel/stage)

set(tools /home/devel/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

see the [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux) where options are explained

**A simple solution** for me was to add following file (or write your own):
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake

to a folder "cmake-modules" where your CmakeLists.txt is located e.g:

```
cmake-modules/FindOpenCV.cmake
```

Then please add

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules)
```

before calling find_package(OpenCV)

**Another idea** for a quick fix is to use the system variable to express, where to find the opencv lib for different cmake targets
calling the follwing command from commadline before calling cmake  :

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=opencv_installation_folder/build
```

or

```
export OpenCV_DIR=opencv_installation_folder/build
```

or write inside your cmake file

```
set (OpenCV_DIR /home/cmake/opencv/compiled) #change the path to match your complied directory of opencv
```

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, you have the package installed in a custom location.

You can try the following (from [the cmake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html)):

> The default search order is designed to be most-specific to
> least-specific for common use cases. Projects may override the order
> by simply calling the command multiple times and using the NO_*
> options:
>
> `find_package (<package> PATHS paths... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)` in your cross compile configuration.

It is also good practice to put all your cross compile options into a so called toolchain file and then use `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchainfile/raspberrypi.cmake ..`

Another option could be to build OpenCV from source, so you do not need to worry if it is already packaged in your toolchain. Replace `find_package` with:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  opencv
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
  GIT_TAG 4.4.0)

FetchContent_GetProperties(opencv)
if(NOT opencv_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(opencv)
  add_subdirectory(${opencv_SOURCE_DIR} ${opencv_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
```